# Copying software application flow or replicating it

Tags: software-industry, law

I worked at an ex-Company where they were creating their own product by almost replicating another renowned Business Intelligence application.

I would like whether this may lead to a lawsuit for the company? That, they are replicating the application or any company is copying flows from an existing application.

Comment: Are they "copying"? Are are they independently creating something that works the same? That's a huge difference.

Comment: What sort of flow? Example: many TVs turn on after you press a button on remote - of that's something you are calling copying a flow - you're mistaken.

Comment: Independently creating something that works the same.

Comment: By flow, I mean, for e.g. in one accounting application, if a company has purchase something, in one application , the company has to create a PV( Purchase Voucher), PV-9-20-00001.

Comment: But in another app, the user does not have to go to PV screen. But go to payments page and then spend Press, Spend Money.

Answer (score 3):

Anything "may lead to a lawsuit" - the other company doesn't have to have a good case to file a complaint. If they have a lot more money to spend, and feel that it's the easiest way to deal with a competitor, they could try to hit you with so many legal documents that the legal fees alone force you to give up.

Then again, if they're that much bigger, they could just spend that money on development and make a better product.

You have raised the issue with your boss, it's his job to check with the company legal team and decide if they want to take the risk. It's not as if they're asking you to do something that's clearly illegal, where it could have consequences to you.